# Google Sheets Conditional formatting to paint row +1 based on 2 conditions

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-statements, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting

I have this pivot table from another sheet, where I need to apply a specific conditional formatting, to understand better, here is an example table

[image]

What I need is:

if in Column F if have cash, then paint the Column I +1 row

in this example im trying to paint I4 in different color, only if in column F I have cash one row above

Any help on this please ?

Answer (score 1):

apply this on range **A4:Z**

```
=$F3="cash"
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got this answer, however, I don't know if it's the best approach:

```
=indirect(address(row()+1,column($F:$F)))="Cash"
```